# How to get back rounded corners in Compiz?

Tags: 20.04, compiz, gnome-flashback, csd

In Ubuntu 20.04 GNOME Flashback with Metacity, all windows had nice rounded corners like on the screen below:

[image: Rounded corners with Metacity]

When I switched to GNOME Flashback with Compiz, non-CSD windows (eg. Firefox or Synaptic) still have those rounded corners, but CSD windows (the ones used by default GNOME applications, like Nautilus) have lost them and now are sharp rectangles:

[image: Sharp corners with Compiz]

Is there any way to bring the rounded corners back?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to you try MATE DE with Compiz. Even after 5 years, it looks [like before](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k_nk02XELi4).  The classic GNOME *desktop* is dead and its illness can't be underestimated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No.

The main problem here is that Compiz does not support `_GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS` atom. GTK uses it to know if window manager knows how to handle client shadow.

I think Ubuntu still have patch that makes all GTK windows transparent... So you might be able to adjust `.solid-csd` CSS to get rounded corners in your theme.

Real fix is to add needed support to Compiz. You can try to use this:
[https://code.launchpad.net/~muktupavels/compiz/gtk-frame-extents/+merge/323427](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Emuktupavels/compiz/gtk-frame-extents/+merge/323427)

It is not merged because it is not ready! Use at your own risk!

Comment: I don't think I want to recompile Compiz, especially with not-yet-ready patches, so I have to wait until this is ready...
I tried to play with CSS you mentioned, but the maximum I was able to achieve is to get rid of thick border around the window (which is good by itself), and make "pseudo-rounded" corners while background triangles above them are neutral-gray. The windows cannot be made transparent in any way. But it looks better than before.

Comment: It should be mentioned that manjaro fixed it already -so it shouldn't be magic to get it done..

Comment: @kanehekili Link to fix?

Comment: [compiz AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/compiz/). In addtion it should be in the manajro repository. Must be compiled for Ubuntu then